# What is best way to use glslc.exe

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I read a litle bit deeper into workings of glslc.exe compiler for glsl shaders. I came across limits and that MaxTextureUnits limit is 2. I read that modern GPUs have much more texture units than 2. I wanted to ask if i need to worry about it and what are best arguments for glslc compiler for most performant shaders?